# Do Lie algebras of non-smooth group schemes over a field admit a Jordan decomposition?

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a perfect field—it will be clear that we might as well take it algebraically closed—and $G$ an affine $k$-group scheme, not necessarily smooth.

A faithful representation $G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ gives rise to a map $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$, *via* which we may speak of the Jordan decomposition in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)(k)$ of an element of $\mathfrak g(k)$.

Is it true that the semisimple and nilpotent parts of the Jordan decomposition actually lies in $\mathfrak g(k)$, and are independent of the representation?  I checked in Demazure and Gabriel - Groupes algébriques - I, which doesn't seem to have it; and in [Milne - Algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781316711736) and [Conrad - Algebraic groups over fields](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110662), which cover the Jordan decomposition only in the group (Section 9(b) and Section 13.1, respectively), where one doesn't see smoothness issues (since $G(k) = G_\text{smooth}(k)$).

This leads me to suspect that the Jordan decomposition might *not* behave well for Lie algebras—but I can't think of a counterexample, and the proof in [Borel - Linear algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6), where technically everything is assumed smooth, doesn't seem actually to use smoothness; in the notation there, it doesn't in any obvious way use that the ideal $J$ defining $G$ as a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is reduced.

Comment: For an affine $k$-group scheme $G:=Spec(A)$ we may define $G(k)$ to be the $k$-points of the affine scheme $G$. If $\mathfrak{g}:=Lie(G)$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ - what do you mean when you write $\mathfrak{g}(k)$?

Comment: @hm2020, [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9712766), $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ is, or can be treated as, a group scheme like any other (in this case a vector group scheme); e.g., if $G = \operatorname{GL}_n$, then $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{gl}_n$, so $\mathfrak g(k) = \mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$.  Many people use $\mathfrak g$ for what I call $\mathfrak g(k)$, and use some other decoration for the vector group scheme. If it bothers you and you believe it's so abnormal as to be likely to confuse others, then feel free to edit.

Comment: what is the precise definition of $\mathfrak{g}(k)$ and where is this studied? If $G$ is a group scheme some authors define $Lie(G)$ using left invariant derivations of the Hopf algebra $A$ (over the base ring $k$). Some authors define it as $Der_k(A,\kappa(e))$ where $e$ is the identity. What is $Lie(G)(k)$ in these situations?

Comment: @hm2020, [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9713704)$\DeclareMathOperator\Lie{Lie}$, obviously you are familiar with definitions of the Lie algebra and know where they are studied. Whereas many authors write $\Lie(G)$ for the Lie algebra, I write $\Lie(G)(k)$ for the very same Lie algebra, defined however you please (as you say, in terms of derivations is fine; or I like $\ker(G(k[\epsilon])) \to G(k))$), and $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ for the resulting vector-group $A \mapsto \Lie(G)(k) \otimes_k A$. It is just different notation for the same object you know.